# Trouble Understanding Prototype chaining

Tags: javascript, frontend

So when i execute the show method of child class why is it giving undefined in the alert box,and what could be the alternative to this

```js
function Parent(relation) {
  this.relation = relation;
}

Parent.prototype.show = function() {
  alert(this.relation);
}

Parent.prototype.parentPrototypeMethod = function() {
  alert("Parent's Prototype Method!");
}

function Child(rel) {

}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype)
var parent1 = new Parent('Father');
var child1 = new Child('Son');
var child2 = new Child('Daughter');

parent1.show();
child1.show();
child2.show();
```

Comment: Do you expect `function Child(rel) {

}` to be replaced with `function Parent(relation) {
  this.relation = relation;
}`  ???

Comment: Your `Child()` constructor ignores the parameter.

Comment: @epascarello i realized after looking at it carefully that i forget to set the relation in the child class

Answer (score 0):

Your `Child()` function is not doing anything, hence the `undefined`. changing it to the following resolves your problem:

```
function Parent(relation) {
   this.relation = relation;
}

Parent.prototype.show = function() {
   alert(this.relation);
}

Parent.prototype.parentPrototypeMethod = function() {
   alert("Parent's Prototype Method!");
}

function Child(relation) {
   this.relation = relation;
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype)
var parent1 = new Parent('Father');
var child1 = new Child('Son');
var child2 = new Child('Daughter');

parent1.show();
child1.show();
child2.show();
```

This is caused by you calling `this.relation` inside

```
Parent.prototype.show = function() {
   alert(this.relation);
}
```

Which did not exist inside `Child()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try not to use prototypes. They are generally bad practice.

The simplest way to add a method to a function is by using overrides.

**Technically, these arent true methods, they are just functions that include a "." in the reference. However, they still functionally act the same. If you want more complex methods with private variables and `this` context.. Youll need to use classes**

like so:

```js
function defaultFunction() {
  return "A Default Function";
}

defaultFunction.chainMethod = () => {
  return "A Chain Method";
};

defaultFunction.chainMethod.inlineChainMethod = () => {
  return "An Inline Chain Method"
};

document.querySelector(".tryChain").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.body.innerHTML += `<hr> ${defaultFunction()}`;
  document.body.innerHTML += `<hr> ${defaultFunction.chainMethod()}`;
  document.body.innerHTML += `<hr> ${defaultFunction.chainMethod.inlineChainMethod()}`;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="tryChain">Try Chain Method</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**This is easily achievable simply be adding a property to the default function, and writing it as an Arrow Expression or Function statement.**

And because its an arrow expression or function statement, you can do add *more* methods to those methods you already created.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to make Child a subclass of Parent, which would require the use of some sort of inheritance pattern. You could change your `Child()` function the following:

```
function Child(relation) {
   Parent.call(this, relation);
}
```

Essentially, using `call()` binds the `this` keyword within the body of the `Parent()` function to the new instance of Child. Any instances of Child will then have access to the methods defined on the Parent prototype.

With that said, if you're not going to add any additional functionality to the `Child()` class, it just becomes redundant, and you could probably get rid of the `Child()` class altogether.